# How to prove comparability property & writing its proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality, proof-writing, relations, real-numbers

I am given the relation in $\mathbb{R}$: $xRy$ if $x\le 2^y$. I want to prove this has the comparability property, so I know I start with let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Then I need to show either $xRy$ or $yRx$. I am not too sure how to go about it.

Comment: If you suppose that it is not comparable, then $x>2^y$ and $y>2^x$, then $x>2^{2^x}$.  Consider the cases where $x\leq 0, 0<x<2$ and $x\geq 2$ separately and find a contradiction.

Comment: Hmm I'm not too sure how you got x>2^2x

Comment: are you aware that if $a<b$ then $2^a<2^b$?  use that knowledge.  Also, note I said 2^(2^x) not 2^(2x)

Comment: Then I do not assume x is less than or equal to y?

Comment: That is irrelevant to the method I am suggesting.

Comment: I get you are saying to do contradiction I just understand what we say is not true. So x not related to y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose for contradictory purposes that $R$ does not have the comparability property.

Then there must be some pair of $x$ and $y$ such that $x\not R y$ and $y\not R x$.  In other words, there must be some pair of $x$ and $y$ such that $x>2^y$ and $y>2^x$.

Since $y>2^x$ implies that $2^y>2^{2^x}$ we have $x>2^y>2^{2^x}$ and in particular we have $x>2^{2^x}$.

Now, one of three things will be true about $x$.  Either $x\leq 0$ or $0<x< 2$ or $x\geq 2$.

- Case 1: $x\leq 0$:  In the case that $x\leq 0$ we have $0\geq x>2^{2^x}$ however since $2^a>0$ for all real $a$ we have $0\geq x>2^{2^x}\geq 2^0=1$ but since $0\not\geq 1$ this is a contradiction.
- Case 2: $0<x<2$:

  > In the case that $0<x<2$ we have $2>x>2^{2^x}$ however since $2^a>1$ for all $a>0$ we have $2>x>2^{2^x}>2^1=2$ but since $2\not > 2$ this is a contradiction.
- Case 3: $2\leq x$: (*left as excercise to reader*)  Use what you know about the comparison of $x$ vs $2^x$ when $x\geq 2$.

---

Since in all three cases we arrive at a contradiction, we see that there cannot be any such $x$ and thus there cannot be any pair $x,y$ such that neither of $xRy$ nor $yRx$ is true, therefore at least one of $xRy$ or $yRx$ must be true and the relation is indeed comparable.

Comment: saying x is not related to y any y is not related to x means x>2^y and y>2^x?

Comment: @Sam precisely, since $x$ **is** related to $y$ means $x\leq 2^y$, that implies that $x$ **is not** related to $y$ means $x>2^y$

Comment: Then how did you go from y>2^x to 2^y>2^2^x

Comment: @Sam $f(x)=2^x$ is a convex monotonic increasing function.  In particular it has the property that $a<b$ implies $f(a)<f(b)$, or rather in this case $a<b$ implies $2^a<2^b$.  Since $y<2^x$ this implies $2^y<2^{2^x}$.  If you don't know why it has this property, then take a moment to prove that as well.  Looking at the derivative of $2^x$ and considering where it is positive should handle that.

Comment: I get it when you say it this way. I understand. Would this be the only way to go about this proof? Or can we say for example we know xRy since it is given x< or equal to 2^y but y is not related to x because we already have or assumption?